# Use Apache Zeppelin with existing Spark Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop2, apache-zeppelin

I want to install Zeppelin to use my existing Spark cluster. I used the following way:

- Spark Master (Spark 1.5.0 for Hadoop 2.4):

  - Zeppelin 0.5.5
- Spark Slave

I downladed the Zeppelin v0.5.5 and installed it via:

```
mvn clean package -Pspark-1.5 -Dspark.version=1.5.0 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -Phadoop-2.4 -DskipTests
```

I saw, that the **local[*]** master setting works also without my Spark Cluster (notebook also runnable when shutted down the Spark cluster).

My problem: When I want to use my Spark Cluster for a Streaming application, it seems not to work correctly. My SQL-Table is empty when I use **spark://my_server:7077** as master - in local mode everything works fine!

See also my other question which describes the problem: [Apache Zeppelin & Spark Streaming: Twitter Example only works local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296894/apache-zeppelin-spark-streaming-twitter-example-only-works-local)

Did I something wrong

- on installation via "mvn clean packge"?
- on setting the master url?
- Spark and/or Hadoop version (any limitations???)
- Do I have to set something special in zeppelin-env.sh file (is actually back on defaults)???

Comment: Just as additional information, have you ever tried the IBM's [spark-kernel](https://github.com/ibm-et/spark-kernel)?

Comment: No I didn't. What is the difference between the "Apache" and the "IBM" version?

Comment: Well, I wrote that comment since I think you are using Zeppelin because you want to run `Scala` notebooks, and the [spark-kernel](https://github.com/ibm-et/spark-kernel) among [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) let you do that.

Comment: Just to be sure - you have a working spark cluster which you can connect to using spark-shell --master spark://my_server:7077 and your code works fine but when you set the zeppelin master property you don't get it to run inside zeppelin?

Comment: Well, I can run my Java Applications (jars) via the spark-submit script. Also the Zeppelin paragraph of the streaming logic seems always to work (local and on "external" spark cluster). The only problem I have is that the %sql part in a second paragraph. Its table is only filled if I run it in local mode (set master to local[*]), and not on spark://master:7077.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by a missing library dependency! So before searching around too long, first check the dependencies, whether one is missing!

```
%dep
z.reset
z.load("org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-twitter_2.10:1.5.1")
```